# Proof of the probability distribution of a binomial and geometric random variables is indeed a valid probability function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-theorem

How can I proof this two theorem?

> **Exercise 3.**<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVbJa.png)</sup> Show that the probability distribution of a binomial random variable $X$ is indeed a valid probability function. That is, show that
> $$ \sum_{j=0}^{n}\operatorname{Pr}(X = j) = 1. $$
>
> **Exercise 6.**<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js6li.png)</sup> Show that the probability distribution of a geometric random variable $X$ is indeed a valid probability function. That is, show that
> $$ \sum_{j\geq 1}\operatorname{Pr}(X = j) = 1. $$

For the binomial random variable the teacher give us a tip that says: "Use the Binomial Theorem or prove by induction"

Comment: For the first one use Binomial Theorem  and for the second use the formula for the sum of a geometric series. Please show some work before you  expect a complete  answer to be posted.

Comment: I'm not a math student, but in this exam there are probability exercises and I'm finding it difficult. I have no idea how to solve these two exercises

Comment: Can you find the expressions for $P(X=j)$? Substitute them and wonder if you can indeed apply the hints.